# PUT not working/saving data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to have it so that when a user clicks a checkbox that the value is true but when they leave it unchecked it goes to false. I want it so they default to true. I have the following as part of my user model.

Part of my user model:

```
newsletterEmail: { type: Boolean, default: 'true'},
  lowerLimitEmail: { type: Boolean, default: 'true'},
  featuresEmail: { type: Boolean, default: 'true'},
  assetOut180: { type: Boolean, default: 'true'},
  lowerLimit: { type: Boolean, default: 'true'},
```

The HTML I have for the checkbox is:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="newsletterEmail" type="checkbox" value="true">
    Newsletter notifications
  </label>
</div>
```

Then inside my route I have this query:

```
User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return (err);
        user.newsletterEmail = req.body.newsletterEmail || false;
        user.lowerLimitEmail = req.body.lowerLimitEmail || false;
        user.featuresEmail = req.body.featuresEmail || false;
        user.assetOut180 = req.body.assetOut180 || false;
        user.lowerLimit = req.body.lowerLimit || false;
        user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return (err);
          req.flash('success', { msg: 'Notification Settings Updated.' });
          res.redirect(req.redirect.success);
        });
      });
```

What is wrong? I took the code from another route and modified it to see if I just wrote the basic part of the route wrong, I that part right, so I am pretty sure is has to do with the query.

Comment: Shouldn't the default values be booleans? They are strings at the moment.

Comment: What? They are booleans look at the first block of code. Says Boolean unless I need to put that somewhere else too.

Comment: I was thinking of the default values, which you have put in quotes when they usually are without. I somehow doubt that will fix anything though, but I might as well mention it.

Comment: @MikaS It shows up in my db when I query it as `true` so I assume it is working.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if you want it to be `true` when the user doesn't check the checkbox, and `true` when it's checked. Why don't you just set the value as `true`?

Comment: @d30jeff  I want it to be false when unchecked and and true when checked with the default of true.